# Flutter Url Launcher doesn't pass the whole text to sms

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send an sms message with the package url launcher in flutter. When I press the button: only this appears in the body of the sms (on android): https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1

But 'Text' is a little bit longer. Is there a solution for this? Thanks!

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                launch(
                    'sms:000000000?body=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=47.751076,-120.740135');
              },
```

I tested the link without the '&' symbol. Than it passes everything. Is there an option to use the & symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use URL encoding for special character in a URL.

So `&` equals `%26`

This will work

```
launch('sms:000000000?body=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1%26destination=47.751076,-120.740135');
```

Other Way is to encode and pass it through `Uri.encodeFull(urlString)` or `Uri.encodeComponent(urlString)`

Like this.

```
launch("sms:" + Uri.encodeComponent('000000000?body=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=47.751076,-120.740135'));
```